# AJAX to populate select not working in webserver

Tags: ajax, select

I have written the following code to populate options into a select list. If one selects "course" from one option list(id="course_id") it fires onchange event. Then AJAX get method calls a php program and passes the course id. The PHP program generates a string as
`<option id="1">Subject1</option> <option id="2">Subject2</option>....` 
I want to assign this string into another select list. The problem is the program runs in local computer OK. But in webserver the 1st test message appears 3 times then message 2 is showing. But Message 2 is not executing nor the data loading. Please help!

```
$('#course_id').change(function(e) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

var first = document.getElementById('course_id');
var course_id = first.options[first.selectedIndex].value;

var param = course_id;
var url = "adm_reposelectSql.php?course_id=" + param;
xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = getThings;
xmlhttp.send();
 });


 function getThings(){
 alert("software testing message 1!");
 if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

 alert("software testing message  2");
var a = xmlhttp.responseText;
$('#subject_id').html(a);
}
  else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status != 200) {
     alert("message 3 No items returned for request");
   }

}
```

Comment: 1st message 3 times then message 3. message not appearing

Comment: Check my answer for your first doubt and i am looking for your second doubt now.

Comment: have you  included jquery in your html file ?

Comment: yes JQuery is included.

Comment: Can you share your complete file  and share your console window of your browser's output as well .

Comment: Try to alert (xmlhttp.readyState +"Status = "+ xmlhttp.status); inside your method. Keep this as the first statement and do let me know about the output.

Comment: given this alert(xmlhttp.readyState + "----" + xmlhttp.status); before  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) showing : 2---200,  3---200 and 4---200 in local computer. I will check and giving you the output of server soon

Comment: With the server , 2---404, 3-404 then 4--404 3 times

Comment: Yes so the problem is resource not found..so check the URL mentioned for the request

Comment: Page not found???!!!!! My god actual name of adm_reposelectSql.php is adm_reposelectSQL.php. Solved!!!! Thanks you taught me how to check a program. Thanks

Comment: Best of luck. :-) and don't forget to up vote the question as well.

Comment: :( vote up requires 15 reputations. I am new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For your first doubt that the first message is being called 3 times

This is happening because this `getThings` method is being called on `onreadystatechange`. The ready states are 1, 2 ,3 ,4 (which is the final state) and for every value this method is being called.

Only for the fourth (4) it enters your if condition
So in your case the first statement in your `getThings` executes for

```
readyState = 1
readyState = 2
readyState = 3
```

Hence is called 3 times.